# DNS name for S3 bucket folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Is it possible to assign a unique domain name for an S3 bucket folder - not the entire bucket but just a folder in the bucket?

For example if I have a bucket s3.amazonaws.com/my.domain.tv and a folder Vasilis/ within that bucket I want to point a domain name vasilis.domain.tv at s3.amazonaws.com/my.domain.tv/Vasilis.

I have found how I can do it for an entire bucket but I couldn't find anything for folders.

Also, can I do it with cloudfront, i.e. create a distribution for a specific folder in a bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a distribution for a specific folder, was just announced in mid-december:

> **Amazon CloudFront Now Allows Directory Path as Origin Name- Date:
>   December 16, 2014**
>
> Details: When you specify the origin for a CloudFront distribution -
>   the Amazon S3 bucket or the custom origin where you store the original
>   version of content - you can now specify a directory path in addition
>   to a domain name. This makes it easier for you to deliver different
>   types of content via CloudFront without changing your origin
>   infrastructure. Learn more by reading our announcement.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/12/16/amazon-cloudfront-now-allows-directory-path-as-origin-name/